# Batch file syntax for multiple criteria?

Tags: batch-file, syntax

is it possible to have an IF statement check two criteria? or would it have to be two IF statements?

I want to say something like "IF a user name is 'owen' or 'oiverson' then GOTO this..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! But there are many different ways to work around.
Try this:

```
set username=Owen
set found=no

if [%username%]==[Owen] set found=yes
if [%username%]==[oiverson] set found=yes

if %found%==yes goto :yes
goto :no

:yes
@echo Found user

:no
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `if` statements together with `goto` like this:

```
rem assuming variable %user% holds the value to check:
if "%user%"=="owen" goto :CondTrue
if "%user%"=="oiverson" goto :CondTrue

:CondFalse
rem ... (none of the conditions is fulfilled)
goto :Continue

:CondTrue
rem ... (one or both conditions are met)

:Continue
rem ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the specific case. For example, if you want to check if a user name is included in a list of names (that seems to be this case), then you may use this method:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "validNames=/owen/oiverson/"

if "!validNames:/%userName%/=!" neq "%validNames%" (
   echo "%userName%" is included in this list: "%validNames%"
)
```

Of course, the list of valid names may have *any number* of names.

If you want that two variables have all a certain specific value (AND on all variables), use this:

```
if "%user%+%version%" equ "expected_user+expected_ver" (
   echo Both variables have the target values
)
```

You may check more than two variables this way.

As I said before, depends on the specific case...